# How to make the <li> item width fit the text length?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make the `<li>` item width fit the text length in Bootstrap 3? My menu item is shorter than the text which causes my `class="active"` to look ugly.

This is the navbar in which it occurs:

```
<div id="menu" class="col-md-1">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Startseite</a></li>
<li><a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please post a demo so that we can know what you're talking about exactly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

make a `.custom_li` class and give

```
.custom_li{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT**

To force same size, i'll suggest using `max-width` and place it under some `media-query`

```
li{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width:50%; /* limit width */
    word-break:break-all; /* wrap extended text*/
    border:1px solid red /* demo */
}
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nLFTr/3/)

[some optional things](http://jsfiddle.net/nLFTr/4/)

[some optional things](http://jsfiddle.net/nLFTr/5/)

Comment: I did this now and it make it look better. How could I make sure that both items have the same size but not shorter than the biggest item?

Comment: Does this work? (edit classes to suit yourself) http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/nLFTr/1/

Comment: not possible through `css`, one way would be to give`max-width`....will add a fiddle...w8 :)

Comment: I tried your other examples too but in my case this is what made it look like I want it to be: #menu > ul { display:inline-block; } You may add it for others.

Comment: what happens in your case?

Comment: The effect of the ``class="active"`` is the same width on every item.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VkC4x/
Here you can see that both items are the same size and if the second item would be clickable it's looking as like as the first one which is active. With your code the blue color of the class active was as long as the text but not as long as the first item. At least it works now and setting display: inline-block; to the ul (not the li) of the menu div was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeShark : all's well thats end well...you got solution,mission accomplished...cheers fella!! :)

Comment: `display: inline-block` takes them out of the flow though and just makes them all `inline` but not `block` for some reason?

Answer (score 9):

When I tried `display: inline-block;` it removes the bullet.

Instead, I use `float:left;` to have them only as wide as text, while preserving the bullet.  Optionally, add `clear:both;` to keep it as a vertical list with each item on a new line.

**CSS**

```
.my-list > li {
    float: left;
    clear: both; /* remove this if you want them flowing inline */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="my-list">
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
    <li>Fourth Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7):

If the `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;` is messing up the alignment.
Then just use `width: fit-content;`

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I did not even know about the value of 'fit-content' for the width property.

Comment: I am glad that it helped

Answer (score 1):

Prevent it becoming a block by adding `display: inline-block;` to the proper element.
Post more code and preferably CSS if you want details.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following css:

```
    ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: fit-content;
}
li{
    display:flex;
    margin: 0.5rem auto;
}
```

Basically what I did was make the container width to fit content.  Used the CSS hack to make sure it would center using the margin.  In the li tag I wanted the contents to be centered so I set it that way

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: inline-block` collapsed my list items, which I didn't want. Using `display: block; width: fit-content` was the solution.